# Stacking multiple columns by condition in R

Tags: r

I have a database in which I have several different emotion variables for two task conditions, for example:

```
   ID      Cond1_sad Cond1_anxious Cond1_happy Cond2_sad Cond2_anxious Cond2_happy
1 C_01         1             7           4         1             3           2
2 C_02         3             6           4         4             6           5
3 C_03         8             6           5         3             4           4
4 C_04         4             5           5         6             8           6
5 C_05         6             4           3         2             6           3
6 C_06         1             4           2         8             1           4
```

I need to stack according to condition, but keep emotion variables in separate columns. For example:

```
    ID    Condition Sad Anxious Happy
1  C_01         1   1       7     4
2  C_02         1   3       6     4
3  C_03         1   8       6     5
4  C_04         1   4       5     5
5  C_05         1   6       4     3
6  C_06         1   1       4     2
7  C_01         2   1       3     2
8  C_02         2   4       6     5
9  C_03         2   3       4     4
10 C_04         2   6       8     6
11 C_05         2   2       6     3
12 C_06         2   8       1     4
```

I have tried various options for stacking the data (e.g. melting them), but end up with all the variables stacked on top of one another. Is there a better solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use `dput` to give us a sample dataset, and please specify the condition (or one of if there are several) so that we can provide tangible answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it in the tidyverse. This should be a bit more flexible than specifying column positions by index.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("Condition", "Emotion"),
               values_to = "Value", names_sep = "_", names_prefix = "Cond",
               names_transform = list(Condition = as.integer)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Emotion", values_from = "Value") %>% 
  arrange(Condition, ID) %>% 
  clean_names("title")

# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#    ID    Condition   Sad Anxious Happy
#    <chr>     <int> <int>   <int> <int>
#  1 C_01          1     1       7     4
#  2 C_02          1     3       6     4
#  3 C_03          1     8       6     5
#  4 C_04          1     4       5     5
#  5 C_05          1     6       4     3
#  6 C_06          1     1       4     2
#  7 C_01          2     1       3     2
#  8 C_02          2     4       6     5
#  9 C_03          2     3       4     4
# 10 C_04          2     6       8     6
# 11 C_05          2     2       6     3
# 12 C_06          2     8       1     4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful! Do you know if/ how I can use the pivot longer function in the case where there is no shared 'Cond' prefix, i.e where conditions are labeled 'S' and 'I'? E.g. if conditions are labeled S_sad, S_anxious, S_happy, I_sad, I_anxious, I_happy? Thanks so much again :)

Comment: If that is the case, just get rid of the `names_prefix` and the `names_transform` arguments from `pivot_longer()` and it should work. The point of those two options is to strip the prefix and then convert it to integer. So if you don't need that, simply remove!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are more conditions, in your given case this will work

```
library(tibble)

df <- data.frame(ID = c("C_01","C_02","C_03","C_04","C_05","C_06"),
                 Cond1_sad = c(1,3,8,4,6,1),
                 Cond1_anxious = c(7,6,6,5,4,4),
                 Cond1_happy = c(4,4,5,5,3,2),
                 Cond2_sad = c(1,4,3,6,2,8),
                 Cond2_anxious = c(3,6,4,8,6,1),
                 Cond2_happy = c(2,5,4,6,3,4))

df1 <- df[,c(1,2,3,4)]
df2 <- df[,c(1,5,6,7)]

df1 <- add_column(df1, Condition = 1, .after = 1)
df2 <- add_column(df2, Condition = 2, .after = 1)

colnames(df1) <- c("ID", "Condition", "Sad", "Anxious", "Happy")
colnames(df2) <- c("ID", "Condition", "Sad", "Anxious", "Happy")

df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)

df3

> df3
     ID Condition Sad Anxious Happy
1  C_01         1   1       7     4
2  C_02         1   3       6     4
3  C_03         1   8       6     5
4  C_04         1   4       5     5
5  C_05         1   6       4     3
6  C_06         1   1       4     2
7  C_01         2   1       3     2
8  C_02         2   4       6     5
9  C_03         2   3       4     4
10 C_04         2   6       8     6
11 C_05         2   2       6     3
12 C_06         2   8       1     4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to do it in `base`. If you really want I am sure you can find a way to remove the indexes and the explicit `v.names`.

```
reshape(df, direction="long",  varying=list(c(2, 5), c(3, 6), c(4, 7)), 
        v.names=c("Sad", "Anxious", "Happy"), timevar = "Condition",
        times = c(1, 2), idvar = F)
```